# Why aren't lvalue casts between pointer types allowed?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

In the Windows [PE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) format, there is a relocation section which contains an array of headers:

```
typedef struct _RELOC_BLOCK_HDR
{
    UINT32 PageRVA;
    UINT32 BlockSize;
} RELOC_BLOCK_HDR, *PRELOC_BLOCK_HDR;
```

And after each header there is an array of values that come after the headers:

```
typedef struct _RELOC_ENTRY
{
    UINT16 Offset : 12;
    UINT16 Type : 4;
} RELOC_ENTRY, * PRELOC_ENTRY;
```

Say we have a pointer to one of the headers:

```
PRELOC_BLOCK_HDR hdr;
```

and we want to apply the byte offset to it to get a pointer to the next header:

```
*(char**)&hdr += hdr->BlockSize
```

This way seems a bit silly. Why can't we use

```
(char*)hdr += hdr->BlockSize
```

to do the same thing? I cannot think of any situation in which such nomenclature would prove ambiguous, or any negative effect it would have on the language.

Comment: What is `buffer` in your case? Why can't you just do `buffer += offset`? Can you modify `offset` to be in units of the `buffer` elements?

Comment: I'd say it's a code smell to do like that. If `buffer` is not a char array, then you could do `char *p = buffer; *p += offset;`

Comment: In order to give sensible answer you should tell us how `buffer` is declared and initialized. And since buffer is presumably pointer, how the variable which is used to initalize `buffer` is declared.

Comment: The correct way to iterate through some generic array/struct of "not character type" byte by byte is: `uint8_t* ptr = (uint8_t*)array; ptr[byte_no] = something;`

Comment: This question is [currently being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388814/i-got-banned-for-no-reason)

Comment: Original/Real/KnR C permitted this construct; but the first standard (c89/90) denied it.   You can perhaps find their rationale somewhere, but don't expect a rational answer.   btw, godbolt has a 386-gcc-1.27 which seems pretty faithful to C.

Answer (score 2):

`*(char**)&hdr += hdr->BlockSize` is wrong under any circumstances. You are casting a `RELOC_BLOCK_HDR**` to a `char**` and these are incompatible types - de-refering this `char**` invokes undefined behavior. So the code is wrong although it might seem "to work" for now.

There is a rule in C allowing us to inspect any other type byte by byte using a character pointer. This special rule applies pointers to character types `char*`/`unsigned char*`/`signed char*` (and likely `uint8_t*`) but it doesn't apply "recursively" to `char**`.

Now as to why `(char*)hdr +=` doesn't work - `hdr` is actually of type `RELOC_BLOCK_HDR*` so you can't do pointer arithmetic on that pointer using a different type and then somehow except it to store the value of that pointer arithmetic as the original type somehow. And misalignment is a serious concern here.

As for what to do with code like this, the least bad choice is to use a temporary variable of character type:

```
uint8_t* byte_ptr = (uint8_t*)hdr;
byte_ptr += hdr->BlockSize;
hdr = (RELOC_ENTRY*) byte_ptr;
```

This too is really fishy and undefined behavior, not guaranteed to work either. But what do you do...

A lot of old, skunky Windows API headers pre-dated flexible array members and utilized the "struct hack", which is what this is a flavour of as well. Other bad practices here are Hungarian notation, hiding pointers behind typedef, the use of `UINT16` for bit-fields and so on. It is impossible to produce well-defined C code out of the structs given.

Properly written code with flexible array members would look like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t     PageRVA;
    RELOC_ENTRY  entry[];
} RELOC_BLOCK_HDR;
```

This assuming that `BlockSize` is the same as `sizeof(RELOC_ENTRY)` - but if it isn't, then all bets are off in the original code as well. In case `RELOC_ENTRY` doesn't come with padding then one has to invent a different wrapper struct 32 bytes large containing 2 `RELOC_ENTRY` objects.